# Setting up Geary with SSL/TLS

Tags: geary

When I open Geary and try adding an email account via IMAP/SMPT I cannot add SSL/TLS or port information. If I simply type in my login information without additional SSL/TLS information, Geary cannot login.
[image]

I found a screenshot on the internet which shows these options for Geary. However, I cannot see them.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the Geary version from the Ubuntu repository. I downloaded the Flatpak version and it worked immediately.

Download: https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.Geary

Install via `flatpak install org.gnome.Geary.flatpakref`.

Answer (score -1):

You have not said what happens if you enter details on the first screenshot and continue. Do you get an error? Other options?

I can't speak for Geary itself but some email clients hide the advanced options. For example some clients would consult a database of known email servers to find what the parameters should be or they may ask for the basics as per your first screenshot., then the client will attempt to connect to the email server, first say using no encryption, if that does not work it may try again using SSL, if that does not work it may try again using SSL/TLS etc etc until it either finds a set of encryption/port parameters that works or if it can't find anything that works it will likely prompt for custom advanced parameters. That way for the majority of users it will "just work" without them having to know or input all the exact parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Nothing happens. The dialogue does not proceed. The login does not work.